# How does the Contacts app handle tabs on tablets?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm writing an app for phones and tablets. Like the Contacts app, there are multiple tabs (2 in my case). For the phone UI, they're managed by a ViewPager, with a fragment for each tab.

But for the tablet UI, each tab is an activity, rather than a fragment. They have to be, because you can't put fragments inside fragments. (Right?)

I realize I could just call `setContentView()` on the tab listener, but wouldn't that destroy the activity every time it was changed? I'm confused by a lot of this.

What's the best way to do this without breaking my phone UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well designed tabbed UI never uses Activities for tab content.

You're correct in that you cannot nest Fragments in the current implementation, but that doesn't mean your only alternative is Activities. Tabs should always act as a view switch; a tab switch never creates navigation history and tab navigation should always happen within the same Activity.

Remember that Activities and Fragments are just controllers from an MVC point of view. They exist to respond to lifecycle events and manage elements of your application in response to those events, including views within your UI. The content of your UI is wholly determined by the view hierarchy of the current window and you can manipulate the view hierarchy in whatever way makes sense for your app. (While preferably still following the design guidelines!)

Since Fragments have a built-in mechanism for managing a view sub-hierarchy they're often a natural choice for factoring your UI but they're not the only way. ViewPager PagerAdapters can manipulate view sub-hierarchies by inflating them from the resource system, recycling views the way a ListView does, or any other mechanism you can come up with and not use Fragments at all if the lifecycle events they provide aren't needed. Different layout resources may include or exclude certain elements based on screen size using different layout variants for different resource qualifiers.

In short, don't get stuck on the idea that Fragments are the only way to do multi-pane UIs, or the only way to implement each page of a ViewPager. They're powerful options for both, but depending on the information architecture of your Activity you may find yourself using them in a different way than another app and that's OK.

Overall, if you're having trouble determining where the logical cut points are when factoring your Activity's UI, you may be building an overall UI for your app that is going to be as awkward to use as it is to implement. Let the UI design guide your implementation. If each tab is naturally switching out the entire content of the Activity window, then each tab might be well suited to a Fragment. Perhaps those Fragments in tablet mode expand their capabilities and present more than one pane in their respective layouts using different layout resources.